# How to decrypt smime file in C# application?

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, mimekit

I have a file, which is encrypted using this command:

> openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -in fileToencrypt -binary -outform DEM -out encryptedFile public_key

It can be decrypted using command:

> openssl smime -decrypt -in encryptedFile -binary -inform DEM -inkey private-key.pem -out decryptedFile

I need to decrypt it using private key (PEM format) in my .NET Core application. What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Cms;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509.Store;

namespace SMimeDecryptExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            AsymmetricKeyParameter key;

            using (var stream = File.OpenRead ("private-key.pem")) {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader (stream)) {
                    var pem = new PemReader (reader);

                    var keyObject = pem.ReadObject ();

                    if (keyObject is AsymmetricCipherKeyPair pair) {
                        key = pair.Private;
                    } else if (keyObject is AsymmetricKeyParameter) {
                        key = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) keyObject;
                    }
                }
            }

            var encryptedData = File.ReadAllBytes (args[0]);
            var parser = new CmsEnvelopedDataParser (encryptedData);
            var recipients = parser.GetRecipientInfos ();
            byte[] decryptedData;

            foreach (RecipientInformation recipient in recipients.GetRecipients ()) {
                decryptedData = recipient.GetContent (key);
                break;
            }

            // now you can do whatever you want with the decrypted data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the file not a MIME message?

Comment: I get format Exception 'Failed to parse message headers', on MimeMessage.Load(). I've tried it with different type of files, encrypted with above mentioned openssl command. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Open up the file in a text editor. Does it *look* like a MIME message? It's a simple thing to figure out. Is it base64? is it binary? What is it?

Comment: It could be any file, generated by openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -in fileToencrypt -binary -outform DEM -out encryptedFile public_key

Comment: *Sigh.* I'm *asking* what format the ENCRYPTED FILE is in, not the original content. I assumed it was in MIME format seeing as how you are using S/MIME encryption, but clearly it is *NOT* in MIME format.

Comment: I just updated my answer to use straight BouncyCastle since you apparently don't need the MIME parsing.